# How to get the Z,Y,X Rotation of Android/iOS Device in React Native? (Pitch,Yaw,Roll)?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I tried using: "react-native-sensors" library

https://github.com/react-native-sensors/react-native-sensors/blob/master/docs/API.md#orientation-observableqx-number-qy-number-qz-number-qw-number-pitch-number-roll-number-yaw-number-timestamp-string

```
import { orientation } from "react-native-sensors";

const subscription = orientation.subscribe(({ qx, qy, qz, qw, pitch, roll, yaw, timestamp }) =>
    console.log({ qx, qy, qz, qw, pitch, roll, yaw, timestamp })
);
```

I tried using their given pitch,roll,yaw and converted from radian_to_degress still not the same values as the emulator.

They also provide a quaternion to Angles function

```
function quaternionToAngles(q) {
    let data = q;

    let ysqr = data.y * data.y;
    let t0 = -2.0 * (ysqr + data.z * data.z) + 1.0;
    let t1 = +2.0 * (data.x * data.y + data.w * data.z);
    let t2 = -2.0 * (data.x * data.z - data.w * data.y);
    let t3 = +2.0 * (data.y * data.z + data.w * data.x);
    let t4 = -2.0 * (data.x * data.x + ysqr) + 1.0;

    t2 = t2 > 1.0 ? 1.0 : t2;
    t2 = t2 < -1.0 ? -1.0 : t2;

    const toDeg = 180 / Math.PI;

    const euler = {};
    euler.pitch = Math.asin(t2) * toDeg;
    euler.roll = Math.atan2(t3, t4) * toDeg;
    euler.yaw = Math.atan2(t1, t0) * toDeg;

    return euler;
}
```

The function gives wrong results for roll,yaw and pitch. I dont want to dive into the Math of this. google searching gives 100x different equations.

[image]

Im searching for simple equations to get the Z,Y,X Rotations of my Device just like the Android Emulator provides. If Z-Rot Value is "90"(on emulator) my program should also receive the same value. I have access to gyrometer,barometer,accelometer etc.

PS: I wasted way to much time on google for a problem that should be solvable with a copy paste after one google search so I hope this question will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'expo-sensors' package.

To answer your question, you can use [DeviceMotion](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/devicemotion/) API or [Gyroscope](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v44.0.0/sdk/gyroscope/) API.
Gyroscope can be used directly from their documentation, so I am providing an example of DeviceMotion.

```js
import { DeviceMotion } from 'expo-sensors'; 

....
....

  componentDidMount(){
    DeviceMotion.addListener((devicemotionData) => {
        console.log(devicemotionData);
        // call to setState reflecting the deviceMotion changes.
        ....
        ....
    });
    // set update delay in ms
    DeviceMotion.setUpdateInterval(100);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    DeviceMotion.removeAllListeners();
  }
....
....
```

the object received by the listener will be in the following format:

```js
{
  "acceleration": {
    "z": -0.0005327463150024414,
    "y": 0.0034074783325195312,
    "x": 0.0005932972417213023
  },
  "accelerationIncludingGravity": {
    "z": -0.8134145140647888,
    "y": -9.769495010375977,
    "x": 0.0011865944834426045
  },
  "orientation": 0,
  "rotation": {
    "gamma": -0.000039085680327843875,
    "alpha": 0.00004289219214115292,
    "beta": 1.4878977537155151
  },
  "rotationRate": { "gamma": 0, "alpha": 0, "beta": 0 }
}
```

for more examples of usage, you can refer to [this article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/tower-a-react-native-device-motion-example-app-8a8e81d333c3)

My android device shows a different kind of measure. maybe this could help you get deductions:

```
alpha range : 0 to 360
beta range : -180 to 180
gamma range : in anticlockwise motion,
    0 to 90 for 1st quadrant,
    90 to 0 for 2nd quadrant, 
    0 to -90 for 3rd quadrant,
    -90 to 0 for 4th quadrant
```